# In EWL, how do I configure email to use an SMTP server which requires username/password?

Tags: configuration, smtp, enterprise-web-library

I know I can change the SMTP server in Standard.xml. But I don't see where I can specify a user name and password for that SMTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config schema doesn't currently support specifying SMTP server credentials. It is certainly possible to add support for this, but nobody has done it yet.